# Is there any solution manual to Halmos' Measure Theory?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

I've spent some time on Halmos' Measure Theory and must upvote such a good book. I want to solve most exercises in this book. I'm not sure whether there is a solution manual or instructor manual that can be downloaded or read online coz solutions are very important for self-study. I've tried to google it several times and results corresponding to my search were not satisfactory.

Comment: I think the best solution is to just post any questions you have here and we'll do our best to help you out.

Comment: @Moya: Yes. That's an effective method. However, typing an exercise with related definitions and my thinking or trials is time consuming. Especially, I have to spend 1 hour or more on typing my confusing proof of an exercise that probably has only a small mistake. Usually, I use solution manual to correct my trails and if there comes a conflict that can not be figured out by myself, I will turn to website for help. And I think it will be a time saved method for both me and the guy who is watching or give comments or answer to my post.

Comment: That's a mildly old book. There are more modern expositions to read.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Can you introduce some of them? Thanks.

Comment: Folland jas book. René Schilling has a nice book, too.

Comment: @Pedro's suggestion is on point. There are a lot of homework solutions from Folland on the internet.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I'm reading Folland's *real analysis and modern technique*. It is a good book as well. However, once I got in trouble showing $f$^$g$ $\mathcal{M}$-measurable if both $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal{M}$-measurable. I got inspired in Halmos' book while material in Folland's seemed to be not sufficient enough.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: Ok, I will try to google them.

Comment: @Bearandbunny after all, did you find the solution?